# Accordion Activate not working

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui-accordion

HTML

```
<div class="faq-left">
    <div class="heading">Common Questions Asked:</div>
    <div class="content-qstions">
        <ul>
            @foreach($questns as $common)
            <li><a href="#" category="{{$common->fk_category}}" id="{{$common->id}}" id="faq-click">{{$common->question}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-right">
    <div class="tab-blugate">
        <div class="accordion">
        @foreach($faqData as $faqItem)
            <h3>{{$faqItem['category']['name']}}</h3>
            <div>
            @foreach($faqItem['faq'] as $fqaQustn)
                <div class="accordion accordion-inner faqQs{{$fqaQustn->id}}">
                    <h3>{{$fqaQustn->question}}</h3>
                    <div>{!!$fqaQustn->answer!!}</div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            </div>
        @endforeach 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".content-qstions li a").click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var className = "faqQs"+id;
 $(className).accordion("activate" , 0 );
});
```

Here I want to activate the accordion both category and question when clicking on the common question.

I tried the above code with click function nad not working properly. Please help on this issue. thanks

Comment: I think `$('.' + className)` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed **period(.)** before your class name. Try below

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var className = "faqQs"+id;
$('.'+ className).accordion("activate" , 0 );
```